# About complex sum and modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n},\,\left(b_{n}\right)_{n}$ two succession of non negative real numbers, $\left(c_{n}\right)_{n}$ a succession of complex numbers and $N$ a large natural number. Suppose that $$a_{n}\leq b_{n},\,\forall n.$$ My question is: is it true that $$\left|\underset{n=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}a_{n}c_{n}\right|\leq\left|\underset{n=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}b_{n}c_{n}\right|?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

\begin{align*}
\{a_n\}&=\{1,0,0,0,\dotsc\} \\
\{b_n\}&=\{1,1,0,0,\dotsc\} \\
\{c_n\}&=\{1,-1,0,0,\dotsc\}
\end{align*}
Then for $N\geq 2$
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\cdot c_n\right|=1
$$
but
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n\cdot c_n\right|=0
$$

One could also concoct a slightly more interesting counterexample. Let
\begin{align*}
a_n&=
\begin{cases}
0 & 1\leq n<M \\
1 & n\geq M
\end{cases} \\
b_n&=1 \\
\{c_n\}&=\{\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\dotsc,\zeta_M,0,0,\dotsc,\}
\end{align*} 
where $\zeta_1,\dotsc,\zeta_M$ are the $M$th roots of unity.
Then for $N\geq M$
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\cdot c_n\right|=1
$$
but
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n\cdot c_n\right|=0
$$

Comment: Thank you! And if $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n},\,\left(b_{n}\right)_{n}$ are two monotone increasing successions?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(a_n) = (c_n) =  -1,1,-1,1...$ and $(b_n) = 2,2,2,2,2,2...$

Comment: $a_n$ and $b_n$ are given as *nonnegative*.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that